# Transparent TextField inside macOS SwiftUI list

Tags: macos, swiftui, textfield

It looks like SwiftUI has an issue on macOS where you can not set a clear background to a TextField inside a List. Is anyone aware of a workaround for this?

I have a simple project [here](https://github.com/andreacipriani/TransparentTextFieldInsideSwiftUIList) where you can reproduce the problem.

[image]

I've tried both with a clear background on a `TextField` and by implementing my custom `NSTextField` with these properties (which is transparent outside a list):

```
    textField.drawsBackground = false
    textField.isBezeled = false
```

Comment: How would you select a text field and type something in it if its background color is set to .clear?  Does Cocoa have one?

Comment: Looking at this in view hierarchy, it seems like that the actual `NSTextView` (that's inside every `NSTextField`, and accessible using `.currentEditor()`) somehow doesn't get exposed when the field is inside a list. It's almost like it gets treated like a cell rather than a real field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* it's like this inside a list, but if you set `drawsBackground` to `true` and the background to `.clear` it works as intended, in your `CustomTextField` struct:

```swift
let textField = NSTextField()

textField.backgroundColor = .clear
textField.isBezeled = false
```

The interesting part is that the actual `NSTextView` inside the label doesn't seem to be exposed to even to view hierarchy when the field lives inside a list. It clearly imposes a strict visual style to a list field, namely `.drawsBackground`.